# Pass multiple arguments or just an ID?

Tags: c, pointers, arguments, global-variables

Developing in C, I have a struct that consists of pointers to other structs, lets say:

```
struct A {
    struct B  *pB;
    struct C  *pC;
    struct D  *pD;
    struct E  *pE;
};
```

Now, I have a global array holds N=100 items of that struct:

```
struct A gl_array[100];
```

When handling one item of the above array, I send to some functions the pointers that the specific item holds. Lets say that I'm sending these arguments to a function named foo_func:

```
int foo_func(struct B *pB_, struct D *pD_)
```

My question - is it better to send only the ID of the item in the array and take its pointers in the function itself, or to send to the function the arguments I want to use as in the example? What is the proper way to handle such case? Maybe it's not an issue at all and I can use both approaches?

Comment: I depends. Will the the function *ever* be called for those pointer when they are not in the `A` structure array? If that will never happen, then it's just a matter of personal preference or style.

Comment: The process handles the items in the global array, and these functions will never be called with pointers that are not part of an item in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int foo_func(struct B *pB_, struct D *pD_)
```

makes the function more general-purpose if it is unnecessary to let foo_func() be aware of the gl_array.

If foo_func() is a private function, I think both are ok.